# NoSuchMethodError: Class '_BigIntImpl' has no instance method 'toJson'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am tried to convert the BigInt to json in dart `Dart SDK version: 2.17.3 (stable) (Wed Jun 1 11:06:41 2022 +0200) on "macos_arm64"`, the code look like this:

```
static Future<bool> updateTodoProperties(Todo todo) async {
    Map<String,Object> params =  new HashMap();
    params.putIfAbsent("id", () => todo.id);
    params.putIfAbsent("name", () => todo.name);
    var response = await RestClient.patch("/tik/todo/v1/update",params);
    if (RestClient.respSuccess(response)) {
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```

when run into this function, show error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: Class '_BigIntImpl' has no instance method 'toJson'.
Receiver: Instance of '_BigIntImpl'
Tried calling: toJson
```

this is the `todo` parameter look like:

[image]

what should I do to fixed this problem?

Comment: Do you actually need `id` to be represented as a `BigInt`?

Comment: yes, in the server side with postgresql, I am using bigint. @julemand101 using int also could work, but I think it is better to keep the same with the server side to avoid facing some problem in the furture.

Comment: `BigInt` in Dart are not the same as `bigint` in PostgreSQL. `bigint` in SQL does just mean signed 64-bit: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html where `BigInt` in Dart means an arbitrary large integer number only restricted by the amount of memory available on your system. So you can just use `int` (which are a signed 64-bit integer) in Dart to represent your `bigint` from SQL.

Comment: what data type should i use in dart to keep the same with server side postgresql? @julemand101

Comment: Updated by comment with the answer. But the answer is just use the builtin `int` type in Dart.

Comment: I assume the server-side expects the params as JSON. So where is the JSON converting part?